# To generate a unique key in django framework

Tags: python, django

In Python-Django,

I am creating an application where I am uploading the image and storing it in the database. For this each image i also want to generate a unique key/number and save it in the database. How can i do so?

I will be using this unique key/number for later verification as i am trying to make a face recognition for detection in contactless fraudlent systems.

Comment: generate unique number after submitting as slug? because pk will do that

Comment: @vaishalimalik do you mean some kind of hash based on the image?

Answer (score 1):

Generating unique key/number is not something related to django itself. For that you can use Python's built-in module uuid. Try following.

```
from uuid import uuid4
uuid4().hex
```

Just a note, generating a unique key/number for image filename is not required. Django itself handles the filenames if you are using models.ImageField for that.